# Does emacs have font-lock for constant values?

Tags: init-file

I am trying to customize a theme for myself, and now I am finding a way to
change the highlight color of constant values such as 10 and 10.5677. For example, C mode in Vim highlights those constant values in blue, while c mode in Emacs does not highlight with any distinctive colors (the currently-highlighted color is black) compared with its counterpart. Based on the [emacs document](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces-for-Font-Lock.html) of font-lock-faces, there is no font-lock to change the highlight color for the constant values.

If you have a solution or have done it before, please let me know.

Comment: For what language? Are colors already in a distinctive color that you want to change, or is the problem how to put constants in a different face from the default?

Comment: Ans1: For any language, but to make this question easier, I would ask for c first. Ans2: I would like to make it different from the default theme. To raise a clearer example, C mode in Vim highlights those constants such as 1 and 10.34 in blue, while C mode for the emacs default theme does not have any distinctive highlight compared with the keywords like int, void, and static.

Comment: https://github.com/Fanael/highlight-numbers perhaps?

Comment: @npostavs Thank you. Your response is the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Some similar questions: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10165/can-i-add-highlighting-in-a-minor-mode, http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10515/regexp-to-font-lock-numbers-but-not-strings, http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28258/modify-modes-font-locking-without-changing-source-code